# Run jquery on each table with same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple tables being generated, and I am calculating a total of the column for each table.

The following works perfectly for the first table, but if I remove the ":first" then it gives me the sum of all tables, which I dont want.

```
var total = 0;
jQuery('table.views-table:first td.views-field-qty').each(function()
{
    var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).text());
    if (!isNaN(price))
    {
        total += price;
    }
});
jQuery('table.views-table:first').after('<p> Total Tickets Sold: <strong>' + total + '</strong></p>');
```

How do I do the above for each table, with a summary under every table, when all classes and td classes are the same. Its no good numbering the table classes, as there could be any amount.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your table in a .each loop

```
jQuery('table.views-table').each(function(i,el){
    var table = jQuery(el);
    var total = 0;
    table.find('td.views-field-qty').each(function()
    {
        var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).text());
        if (!isNaN(price))
        {
            total += price;
        }
    });
    table.after('<p> Total Tickets Sold: <strong>' + total + '</strong></p>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to amend your logic so that you call `each()` on the table and then again on each `td` within that table. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('table.views-table').each(function() {
        var $table = $(this), total = 0;
        $table.find('td.views-field-qty').each(function() {
            total += parseInt(jQuery(this).text(), 10) || 0;
        });
        $table.after('<p> Total Tickets Sold: <strong>' + total + '</strong></p>');
    });
});
```

Note that you can negate the need for the `if` statement by using the `||` operator as a shortcut to providing a default value for the variable.

Comment: Stunning. Thank you!